# Saving the spinner position or value using Shared Preference

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view, android-spinner

I am in my Fragment class which has spinner that contains locales..for text to speech

```
    mylocale = localeList.get(position);
    textToSpeech.setLanguage(mylocale);
    spinnerposition = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(localeList.get(position)));
```

i want to save the position using `sharedpreferences` this is what i am trying:

```
 public void savepos(){
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt(POSITION , spinnerposition);
    editor.apply();
}
```

i have declared spinner position as Global variable

```
int spinnerposition;
```

here's how i retrieve the position:

```
public void saveposload(){
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    int position = sharedPreferences.getInt(POSITION ,1);

    mspinner.setSelection(sharedPreferences.getInt(POSITION, position));
}
```

but i am not able to do so, app crashes please help

heres the exception from log

```
2018-12-30 15:13:49.904 3611-3611/my.uapp.com E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: my.uapp.com, PID: 3611
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "it_IT"
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:521)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:611)
    at my.uapp.com.Tab0$override.onItemSelected(Tab0.java:363)
    at my.uapp.com.Tab0$override.access$dispatch(Tab0.java)
    at my.uapp.com.Tab0.onItemSelected(Tab0.java)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:931)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:920)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.-wrap1(AdapterView.java)
    at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:890)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: What error shows in logcat?

Comment: 2018-12-30 17:10:59.985 1630-1644/system_process I/ActivityManager: Killing 4617:my.uapp.com/u0a62 (adj 0): crash

Comment: seems like there's no errors associated...only crash is stated

Comment: @AmanthRai Check the part in the logcat that begins with FATAL EXCEPTION or java.lang.RuntimeException

Comment: what is `it_IT ` in your code??

Comment: Theres no it_IT in my code

Comment: your error is in this line `spinnerposition = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(localeList.get(position)));
`

is above line in `onItemSelected()`

Comment: yeah i replaced it with spinnerposition = mspinner.getselecteditemposition();

Comment: @AmanthRai now is it working?

`spinnerposition = position;` try this

Comment: App opens but the spinner state is not saved... The spinner position falls back to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `localeList` the list where you store all the locales, like `"it_IT"`, etc?
If this is the case then this:

```
localeList.get(position)
```

is a **String** and it cannot be parsed to **int** with this line:

```
spinnerposition = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(localeList.get(position)));
```

Maybe you only need this:

```
public void saveposload(){
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    mspinner.setSelection(sharedPreferences.getInt(POSITION, 0));
}
```

Make sure that you call `saveposload()` after you set the adapter.

Comment: Yes... localelist is the list where i have all the locales.

Comment: Change the line to `spinnerposition = position;` and check if this works;

Comment: You must debug, is `position` in your code the actual spinner's position? If it is then you can save it. I don't have the full code of your app so I'm just guessing. The problem with the crash is solved I believe and the value is saved in SharedPreferences. Your problem now is which value is saved right? So debug.

Comment: Spinner is getting it's position from localelist that stores the locales for tts. localelist.get(position).

Comment: Then position has the right value. Check my edited answer and debug in saveposload() to see the value returned.

Comment: Sure i am figuring out.

Comment: Make sure that you call saveposload() after you set the adapter.

Comment: Awesome... @forpas at first i was calling it on... Oncreate, as you said i now called it after setting the adapter  and here it is working.... Thank you so much for your help.... WORKED OUT!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
            long id) {
         mylocale = localeList.get(position);
         textToSpeech.setLanguage(mylocale);
         savpos(position);
    }

    public void savepos(int position) {
        sharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("stored_position", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("pos" , position).apply;
     }

   public void saveposload(){
      sharedPreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("stored_position", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
      int position = sharedPreferences.getInt("pos",0);  //zero being the default value
      mspinner.setSelection(position);
    }
```

put a break point on the saveposload() and check if the position retrieved properly or now. and where are you calling the `saveposload()`

And you don't need to store position in `private Spinner firstSpinner;`

Comment: saveposload() is on onCreate

Comment: call it in `onStart()` and try above if this work's!
@AmanthRai

Comment: As @forpas said i called it after setting the spinner adapter... And it's working now... And thank you for your help and code.